# Have Time showing up only in hours and not converted to days

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

I have a table were I get the time worked for this week. However it shows the time in "days hours minutes". I would prefer only hours. Is that possible?

```
* work clock tasks week
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 3 :narrow 100 :scope file :tstart "<-1w>" :tend "<now>" :step week :link

Weekly report starting on: [2019-01-15 ter]
| Headline                                                       | Time       |       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------|
| *Total time*                                                   | *1d 10:33* |       |

...

#+END:
```

So I would like Total time to show 34:33 instead of 1d 10:33. Is that possible?

Comment: It would answer you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720526/set-clock-table-duration-format-for-emacs-org-mode

Comment: Thanks! So I should change this globally and not only for this table.